# Wake On Lan issues on Ubuntu 20.04 including some sort of shutdown crash after wake on lan

Tags: networking, shutdown, crash, reboot, wakeonlan

I just upgraded my NAS server from 18.04 to 20.04 (Clean install, wiped the old drive completely) and now I am having issues with Wake on Lan, and even rolling back to 18.04 won't fix the issue.

**My Hardware**

Motherboard: MSI Z87M Gaming Motherboard

CPU: Intel Core i5 4590

GPU: evga GTX 960

NIC1: Atheros Killer E2200 On board

NIC2: hp nc364t quad gigabit PCI-E Adapter

**The Issues**

*Issue 1*

The on board NIC reports that wake on lan is not supported in ethtool, despite me previously being able to use it with wake on lan before I upgraded and wake from PCI-E events being enabled in bios

*Issue 2*

Although I am able to enable wake on lan on the ports of the hp card, after I turn on the computer using wake on lan any future shutdown call will result in what seems to be a crash (tons of errors printing to the console which don't seem to be logged and disappear before I can read them in detail) and the computer restarts.

I could live without getting wake on lan working on the on board card, but not being able to remotely shut down the computer reliably is going to be a huge problem for me (huge waste of power) I only use this computer periodically for backups.

**Attempt at a solution**

I have tried:

- Reinstalling 20.04 (Several times, same issue persists)
- Rolling back to 18.04 (Same issue persists)
- Removing all hardware and peripherals except for NICs and GPU
- Resetting BIOS/UEFI and only enabling WOL related options (e.g. wake from PCI-E events)
- Updating GPU drivers from nVidia's website
- Installing this patch: https://github.com/AMV007/alx_dkms_installer (on-board NIC reported that WOL is supported and enabled for physical activity and magic packets but wol packets never seemed to reach the device when listening to port 9 on udp, and I could not get it to turn on)
- Disabling on-board NIC and only using HP card (Stil get the shut down issue)
- Updating the HP card drivers using the intel drivers found here: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/15817/Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-PCIe-Intel-Gigabit-Ethernet-Network-Connections-Under-Linux-?product=20720

I would try removing the HP NIC, but I can't get WOL to work with the on board NIC so I can't even recreate the issue. I haven't tried removing the GPU because I don't have any other way to display at the moment (I need the DVI connection) I want to keep the GPU in there ultimately anyway because I use it for training neural networks and some CUDA code.

At this point I am completely at a loss but I am willing to try anything suggested, I just want to get this working before the week is out because I will be traveling soon and I want this set up properly before I leave.